# Unable to like a tweet using twitter4j but everything else is working fine

Tags: spring-boot, twitter, twitter4j

Here is the code which is working fine for other methods of twitter variable but only createfavorite is giving this error :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;


public class TwitterAutoLikerPart1 {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwitterAutoLikerPart1.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("E")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("F")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("G")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("H");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        var twitter = tf.getInstance();
        long tweetid=tweetid;
        logger.info("Tweet id is "+tweetid);
        logger.info(twitter.createFavorite(tweetid).getText());
       /*
Whereas this is working 
 for(var x:twitter.getFavorites())
            logger.info(x.toString());*/

    }


}
```

Here's the logs for your referrence :

```
Exception in thread "main" 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
{"request":"\/1.1\/favorites\/create.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST."}

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=038fb9e8 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=480cbeca
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[038fb9e8-480cbeca], statusCode=401, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.7}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:170)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.post(HttpClientBase.java:86)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:2102)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.createFavorite(TwitterImpl.java:1241)
    at com.twiiterapi.mt.twitterapi.TwitterAutoLikerPart1.main(TwitterAutoLikerPart1.java:30)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Kindly let me know where am I faultering.

**Edit:** *So, the issue was app permission as pointed by the kind person Mr Andy Piper . I changed the permission and it started working like a charm* .

Comment: The error says that your app only has read permissions, have you checked that you have write permissions in the developer portal?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering . After the app settings changed with the help of your answer only https://twittercommunity.com/t/changing-app-permissions-missing-in-ui/163708/9    
This worked like a charm . Thanks a lot